# Node Windows NPM not installing

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

I'm trying to simply install a stupid package in Node. I use the normal ol' command and it proceeds to tell me it can't find a file or directory (see image below). I've already updated and reinstalled npm, and still the same thing. I'm also running Windows 8. Any ideas, please?

Should I give up developing Node on a Windows machine?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You definitely don't want to be installing NPM packages under `C:\Users`. That could easily replace your home directory with a package.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I switched back to my user directory. Should I be in the node directory or does it really not matter where?

Comment: You should be in your project's top-level directory, run `npm init` as @drscaon answered, then `npm install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `npm init` first and it will create the package.json file that it is looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I switched back to the user directory, then ran that command, hit enter a million times, then it created the package file. I then ran `npm install bl` and it didn't seem to throw any errors, just warnings that my package didn't have a description or repository field.